# Habilitar o Deshabilitar un Input dependiendo del radio button seleccionado

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código HTML el cual consta de dos Radio Buttons. Necesito que si el usuario elige uno, dependiendo de cual sea el mismo, el campo "Discount Percentage" este activo o no.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="isProductDiscounted" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Is Product Discounted?</label>
    <div class="btn-group w-100" data-toggle="buttons" name="isProductDiscounted">
        <label class="btn btn btn-blue-grey waves-effect w-50 form-check-label active">
            <input id="isDiscounted" class="form-check-input" name="isDiscounted" type="radio" value= 0 th:field="*{discounted}" autocomplete="off" checked> No discounted
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn btn-blue-grey waves-effect form-check-label w-50">
            <input id="isNotDiscounted" class="form-check-input" name="isDiscounted" type="radio" value= 1 th:field="*{discounted}"> Discounted
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="discountPercentage" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Discount Percentage</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="discountPercentage" th:field="*{discountPercentage}">
    <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('discountPercentage')}" th:errors="*{discountPercentage}"></small>
</div>
```

Por default, al cargar la pagina el radio button seleccionado es el "No discounted". He intentado con el siguiente código, pero no funciona del todo, ya que el input siempre esta des habilitado cualquiera sea el radio button seleccionado.

```
var discounted = document.getElementById('isDiscounted');
var no_discounted = document.getElementById('isNotDiscounted')
var discount_percentage = document.getElementById('discountPercentage')

if(discounted.checked) {
    discount_percentage.disabled = true;
} else  {
    discount_percentage.disabled = false;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si usaras jQuery seria mas facil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que no estás escuchando los cambios en los botones de radio, encapsula todo en una función y agrega listeners a ambos para que puedan cambiar el estado cada que das click en alguno de ellos

El código quedaría de esta manera:

```js
var discounted = document.getElementById('isDiscounted');
var no_discounted = document.getElementById('isNotDiscounted')
var discount_percentage = document.getElementById('discountPercentage')

function updateStatus() {
  if (discounted.checked) {
    discount_percentage.disabled = true;
  } else {
    discount_percentage.disabled = false;
  }
}

discounted.addEventListener('change', updateStatus)
no_discounted.addEventListener('change', updateStatus)
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="isProductDiscounted" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Is Product Discounted?</label>
  <div class="btn-group w-100" data-toggle="buttons" name="isProductDiscounted">
    <label class="btn btn btn-blue-grey waves-effect w-50 form-check-label active">
            <input id="isDiscounted" class="form-check-input" name="isDiscounted" type="radio" value= 0 th:field="*{discounted}" autocomplete="off" checked> No discounted
        </label>

    <label class="btn btn btn-blue-grey waves-effect form-check-label w-50">
            <input id="isNotDiscounted" class="form-check-input" name="isDiscounted" type="radio" value= 1 th:field="*{discounted}"> Discounted
        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="discountPercentage" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Discount Percentage</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="discountPercentage" th:field="*{discountPercentage}" disabled>
  <small class="form-text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('discountPercentage')}" th:errors="*{discountPercentage}"></small>
</div>
```